# LDAP Authentication in limesurvey

Tags: limesurvey

Can anybody point me to any useful instructions for setting up admin authentication via LDAP in limesurvey?

The limesurvey wiki has a page unchanged since 2011 about setting up a "Cheap and dirty" LDAP authentication, but I suspect that this no longer applies since 2.00 anyway.

There is a reply to a bug report saying that 2.05 beta has a plug-in mechanism including LDAP authentication, but I've been unable to find any information about this - even anything on how to download and install the 2.05 in the first place.

Limesurvey's Community facilities seem to be a dead loss: I can't get a reply on IRC, and while my query has only been on the forum since yesterday I'm not hopeful.

I'm hoping that somebody here may have more useful information.

Comment: A well deserved +1 For the search you did, Colin. I don't know the first thing about Limesurvey, but I know your pain.

Comment: What ldap server are you targetting ? I suggest you add the ldap tag to your question, along with the specific ldap server you are referring to, in any.

Answer (score 2):

2.05 have whole mechanism in Plugin. After installation, go to plugin settings and activate LDAP.

Answer (score -1):

This is easy but I'm afraid it is not what you want. In `application/config/config.php`, you change this :

```
$config['enableLdap'] = true;
```

Then configure your LDAP directory in `application/config/ldap.php`. Most [options are described here](http://manual.limesurvey.org/wiki/LDAP_settings#Defining_LDAP_servers). You will have to change the LDAP paths and queries, especially if you are using ActiveDirectory. Why I mention this will be clear later on.

LDAP authentication can be done, but there is nothing out the box. IIRCC (if I read the code correctly). The login procedure ends up calling [UserIdentity::authenticate](https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/blob/master/application/core/UserIdentity.php#L70). Following along from (at line 70 in version `ad10c28354431e09c3e82800721427bee31c6598`), I came up with this

In config.php, change this

```
$config['auth_webserver'] = true;
```

Which will delegate authentication to the web server. Use anything that will set the `REMOTE_USER` variable. That's vague, I know. But Limesurvey only gives you two choices : internal database or external. We must choose external, where we will configure LDAP authentication and HTML forms that somewhat match Limesurvey's.

The upside is that you could use IIS to set `REMOTE_USER`, acheving single sing-on if you are setting this in an internal Microsoft based network.

With that in place, you will have to write code that implement `hook_get_auth_webserver_profile`. It would mean to look up the user in LDAP, maybe using the parameters found in `ldap.conf`.

It is a lot of work, but you can make a proof of concept easily. Change the configuration as mentionned, hardcode `hook_get_auth_webserver_profile` for a given user and login to Limesurvey by forging a REMOTE_USER http header of your choice.

Comment: Broken link? Here's another manual entry for LDAP configuration in LimeSurvey: https://manual.limesurvey.org/LDAP_settings